# Convert txt into xls

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to copy across info from a txt file and place it in the xlsm file splitting at a certain number of rows then continuing on the next worksheet (the txt file has over 2 million rows).

The issue I have is that it doesn't copy the first 700,000 rows but does copy the rest, also in the first worksheet it pastes Chinese in there I am unsure whether this has something to do with the info coming from a txt file. Can someone point out where I have gone wrong?

```
Sub SplitTxt_01()

Const HelperFile As String = "ABCD" 
Const N As Long = 699998  
Dim myPath
 myPath = "D:\Test\" 
Dim myFile
 myFile = "20181129_EXPORT_RESULTS.txt" 

Dim WB As Workbook, myWB As Workbook
 Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim myWS As Worksheet
Dim t As Long, r As Long
Dim myStr

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


myFile = Dir(myPath & myFile)
Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1
t = 1
r = 1
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, myStr
    If r > N Then
        t = t + 1
        r = 1
    End If
    Open myPath & HelperFile & t & ".txt" For Append As #2
    Print #2, myStr
    Close #2
    r = r + 1
Loop
Close #1

For i = t To 1 Step -1
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myPath & HelperFile & i & ".txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set myWS = myWB.Sheets.Add
    myWS.Name = HelperFile & i
    Rng.Copy myWS.Cells(1, 1)
    WB.Close False
Next
myWB.Save

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fldr = Fso.GetFolder(myPath)

For Each Filename In Fldr.Files
    If Filename Like "*" & HelperFile & "*" Then Filename.Delete
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You set N to be 699998,
then have a test that if r < n, both t and r are not incremented...

So only after r is greater than N will it start copying rows.

At least that is how I read it...